# Writing JSON data to a JSON file

Tags: json, file, laravel, logging, laravel-5

Hello in my application I am currently trying to create my own custom log files in .json format.  Reason for this is because I want a well structured and accurate log file which can be easily read and would not depend on some special code in my application to read the data.

I have been able to create a json file: activities.json
I have been able to write and append to that file using `File::append($path, $json)`

**This is a sample of the file contents:**

```
{"controller":"TestController","function":"testFunction()","model":"Test","user":"Kayla","description":"Something happened!! Saving some JSON data here!","date":"2016-06-15"}
{"controller":"TestController","function":"testFunction()","model":"Test","user":"Jason","description":"Something happened!! Saving some JSON data here!","date":"2016-06-15"}
{"controller":"UserController","function":"userFunction()","model":"User","user":"Jason","description":"Another event occurred","date":"2016-06-15"}
```

Now my issue is the above is not a valid JSON. How do I get it in this format:

```
[
 {"controller":"TestController","function":"testFunction()","model":"Test","user":"Kayla","description":"Something happened!! Saving some JSON data here!","date":"2016-06-15"},
    {"controller":"TestController","function":"testFunction()","model":"Test","user":"Jason","description":"Something happened!! Saving some JSON data here!","date":"2016-06-15"},
    {"controller":"UserController","function":"userFunction()","model":"User","user":"Jason","description":"Another event occurred","date":"2016-06-15"}
]
```

Is there a way of writing and appending to a json file in laravel?  As much as possible I want to avoid reading the entire file before the append and doing a search and replace since the file may contain hundreds to thousands of records.

I will not use the default Laravel Log function.

Comment: If you "append" json, the entire file will _not_ be valid JSON. You have to read in the whole thing, decode, append, re-encode, and write back to file. Which is obviously not ideal at all. JSON is a poor choice for an append-only file where you want to easily load and parse later.

Comment: Yes I know that, can you please tell me what your suggestion is? Should I just save it as a .txt instead and read it line by line into a JSON array whenever I want to display the contents in my app?

Comment: This seems to be begging for a database. Flat file is great for log files, thing you may need to use for troubleshooting, etc. But if you know in advance you will need to load/parse and display the data in your app, flat file makes your life more difficult. Even sqlite (which Laravel supports) would make this all so much easier.